# Streaming HEVC SRT from ffmpeg to ffplay through ethernet, how can I determine latency and cpu usage of each step?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, latency

I'm streaming desktop capture from a Windows 10 computer indirect display on two monitors to a Raspberry Pi 4's two hdmi output ports.

Now the RPi 4 is getting maxed out on the cpu when running two streams. There is also varying latency which is difficult to measure.

My settings are the basic I could gather from the manual and various posts and still need a lot of tuning.

To perform this tuning, I need accurate measurements of the latency of each step, and if possible, to know how much cpu is used by each step.

Roughly the steps are screen grabbing, hardware encoding, packing in SRT container, sending over network, receiving over network, unpackaging SRT, hardware decoding and display.

Various settings, such as changing container format, changing buffer length, changing video quality and probably a lot more settings I haven't found yet, are going to impact the latency, cpu usage and frame rate and this is why I'm asking how to measure these aspects.

So that I can tune the vast array of ffmpeg parameters and observe the difference they make in an objective and accurate manner.

Here are my current settings

on the windows PC

ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -video_size 1680x1050 -offset_x 1920 -offset_y +525 -i desktop -vcodec hevc_nvenc -f mpegts srt://mypi.lan:6667

On the raspberry pi

ffplay -fs -f mpegts srt://:6666?mode=listener

While both software are running, they output basic metrics

(ffmpeg)
frame=   85 fps= 28 q=21.0 size=     343kB time=00:00:03.03 bitrate= 926.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.996x

(ffplay)
83869.57 M-V:  0.036 fd=1330967 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0

This information is constantly being overwritten in the terminal and I see no way to turn it into an histograph, it is also incomplete, for instance ffplay has no information regarding the frame rate or bitrate, vq is a rough estimate of latency except with the varying bitrate it is too hard to estimate at a glance what the latency is. Also vq is the video queue size and does not represent the whole system latency.